# Pandas rolling OLS being deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

When I run an old code, I get the following warning: " pandas.stats.ols module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. We refer to external packages like statsmodels".
I could not understand if there is a user-friendly rolling OLS module in statsmodel. What was nice about the pandas.stats.ols module was that you could easily state if an intercept was or not needed, the type of window (rolling, expanding) and the window length. Is there a module that does exactly the same?

For example:

```
YY = DataFrame(np.log(np.linspace(1,10,10)),columns=['Y'])
XX = DataFrame(np.transpose([np.linspace(1,10,10),np.linspace(‌​2,10,10)]),columns=[‌​'XX1','XX2'])
from pandas.stats.ols import MovingOLS
MovingOLS( y=YY['Y'], x=XX, intercept=True, window_type='rolling', window=5).resid
```

I would like an example of how to get the result of the last line (the residual of the moving ols) using statsmodel or any other module.

Thanks

Comment: related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317727/deprecated-rolling-window-option-in-ols-from-pandas-to-statsmodels)

Comment: I tried to ask this question in that question but the moderator removed it. the answer to that question does not seem to work with dataframes

Comment: basically, I think it would be useful to see an example on how to do the rolling OLS in statsmodel without having to go through cumbersome list comprehensions or other iterations.

Comment: If you want to see examples provide a sample input data set and desired output data set. Pleas read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You should edit your question, put the properly formatted code in there, then ping Max so he can have another look.

Answer (score 3):

I created an `ols` module designed to mimic pandas' deprecated `MovingOLS`; it is [here](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/master/pyfinance/ols.py).

It has three core classes:

- `OLS` : static (single-window) ordinary least-squares regression.  The output are NumPy arrays
- `RollingOLS` : rolling (multi-window) ordinary least-squares regression.  The output are higher-dimension NumPy arrays.
- `PandasRollingOLS` : wraps the results of `RollingOLS` in pandas Series & DataFrames.  Designed to mimic the look of the deprecated pandas module.

Note that the module is part of a [package](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance) (which I'm currently in the process of uploading to PyPi) and it requires one inter-package import.

The first two classes above are implemented entirely in NumPy and primarily use matrix algebra.  `RollingOLS` takes advantage of broadcasting extensively also.  Attributes largely mimic statsmodels' OLS `RegressionResultsWrapper`.

An example:

```
# Pull some data from fred.stlouisfed.org
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

syms = {'TWEXBMTH' : 'usd', 
        'T10Y2YM' : 'term_spread', 
        'PCOPPUSDM' : 'copper'
       }
data = (DataReader(syms.keys(), 'fred', start='2000-01-01')
        .pct_change()
        .dropna())
data = data.rename(columns=syms)
print(data.head())
                # usd  term_spread   copper
# DATE                                     
# 2000-02-01  0.01260     -1.40909 -0.01997
# 2000-03-01 -0.00012      2.00000 -0.03720
# 2000-04-01  0.00564      0.51852 -0.03328
# 2000-05-01  0.02204     -0.09756  0.06135
# 2000-06-01 -0.01012      0.02703 -0.01850

# Rolling regressions

from pyfinance.ols import OLS, RollingOLS, PandasRollingOLS

y = data.usd
x = data.drop('usd', axis=1)

window = 12  # months
model = PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=x, window=window)

# Here `.resids` will be a stacked, MultiIndex'd DataFrame.  Each outer
#     index is a "period ending" and each inner index block are the
#     subperiods for that rolling window.
print(model.resids)
# end         subperiod 
# 2001-01-01  2000-02-01    0.00834
            # 2000-03-01   -0.00375
            # 2000-04-01    0.00194
            # 2000-05-01    0.01312
            # 2000-06-01   -0.01460
            # 2000-07-01   -0.00462
            # 2000-08-01   -0.00032
            # 2000-09-01    0.00299
            # 2000-10-01    0.01103
            # 2000-11-01    0.00556
            # 2000-12-01   -0.01544
            # 2001-01-01   -0.00425

# 2017-06-01  2016-07-01    0.01098
            # 2016-08-01   -0.00725
            # 2016-09-01    0.00447
            # 2016-10-01    0.00422
            # 2016-11-01   -0.00213
            # 2016-12-01    0.00558
            # 2017-01-01    0.00166
            # 2017-02-01   -0.01554
            # 2017-03-01   -0.00021
            # 2017-04-01    0.00057
            # 2017-05-01    0.00085
            # 2017-06-01   -0.00320
# Name: resids, dtype: float64
```